# Losing API JWT authentication on Angular rebuild

Tags: .net, angular, authentication, jwt, webapi

Sorry if this is not appropriate for this forum, but I'm not sure what to do.  I am not posting code here because I'm hoping this question will prompt suggestions of 3-4 things I can look at/try.

I am using 2 boilerplates made available by a gifted developer: a C# .net core webAPI and Angular 10 interface and MS SQL db.  I was able to get them working with my db where it was authenticating, etc., and I was beginning to customize it, add basic functionality, forms, and such.  I did something, however, where I broke it and my most recent save to GitHub was much older than I realized.  I ended up having to piece it back together again, but apparently missed something.

Authentication works fine.  The ONLY issue I'm facing is that now when I do the Save All in MS Code on the Angular interface (and the interface refreshes), I have to sign in again.  It didn't do that before and I'd really like to get back to where I don't have to sign in every time I do a Save All.

Any suggestions for what I might check to see why the authentication is not surviving the refresh?  Thanks very much in advance.

[New info 7/12/2021]

```
[authenticate and refresh-token code][1]
[setTokenCookie code][2]
[getRefreshToken code][3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue had to do with the SameSite settings (my code had none)

I added the following to CookieOptions

Secure = true,
SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,

Fixed it right up!

Answer (score 0):

It is common to put the JWT in localstorage and then read it out on refresh. Perhaps this was missed?

Do you see anything saved in localstorage?
[Example localstorage from Chrome developers tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZtnx.png)

If so then it is probably missing reading out the JWT on refresh, look for localstorage in your Angular project and if found and it is reading a JWT out then run that code on refresh for example some autologin code might look like:

```
 autoLogin() {
    const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    if (!userData) {
      return;
    }
    const loadedUser = new User(userData.email, userData.id, userData._token, new Date(userData._tokenExpirationDate));
    return loadedUser;
  }
```

And that code might be run on startup in app.component.ts (by default the bootstrapping component in Angular):

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.authService.autologin();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is just the kind of lead/suggestion I was hoping for.  

The JWT is stored in the SQL db in the RefreshToken table, and is updating when I sign in and as tokens expire.  When I refresh, I still have to sign in again, even though the previous refresh token is still in the table.  The tokens have a life of 1 week.

Comment: Upon deeper review, it is clear the api is supposed to be writing a cookie to the computer but is not.  The Refresh-Token method looks for that cookie and compares it to the db, and of course is not finding a match since there is no cookie to begin with.  I'm certain once I solve the cookie writing issue it will all work again.

Comment: Cookie is a bit less common than localstorage because the cookie is sent with any request not just the ones you specify in an interceptor. Are you sure it isn't just looking for a token in the authorization header?  ``` const authReq = !!user ? req.clone({
          setHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + user.token },
        }) : req; ```

Comment: Thank you Wild Bill.  I posted some snips of code

It appears to me that refresh-token is looking for the refreshToken cookie to get the token value, then checking the db for the existence of the token in the table.  The refreshToken cookie is not being written in the first place, so it errors out.

The strange thing is it worked just fine before, and on this same computer.  I don't know why it is not writing the cookie.